# Angular5 Getting data from observable to component

Tags: html, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular5

I try to take data from observables to component.

I can not get the data into the array in the typescript, I still get the Observable object and the message of type negatives. However, in HTML the loop correctly prints the data that came.

Services :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private _dataListSource: BehaviorSubject<Data[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Data[]>([]);


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getDataList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<Data[]>('/rest/data/lastDatas').map(res => {
            this._dataListSource.next(res);
            console.log(res);
        });
    }

    subscribeToDatas(): Observable<Data[]> {
        return this._dataListSource.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();
    }

    getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
        return this.http.get<Data[]>('/rest/data/lastDatas');
    }
}
```

TypeScript class:

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

    dataStatuses: Data[];

    public dataList$: Observable<Data[]>;

    constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataList$ = this.dataService.subscribeToDatas();
        this.dataService.getDataList().subscribe();
        console.log("Informacja ", this.dataList$);
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div *ngIf="dataList$ | async; let dataList; ">
  <div *ngFor="let data of dataList">
    {{data.id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you getting in console.log(); ??

Comment: Informacja  Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dataList$` returns an `Observable`, that is correct. The html still works because you are using an [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), which automatically does the "subscribe" part for you in HTML.

If you want to see what does `dataList$` return, simply subscribe to it:

```
this.dataList$.subscribe(data=>{
    console.log("data from dataList! ",data);
})
```

Comment: its working thanks! I try to put object lamp to my dataObjects array. And its not working.  i try do this by dataObjects.push(data)

Comment: Just a reminder to accept answers that solved your question!